# remove certain pattern in string in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following json strings:

```
{"date":12455}
{"date":12455,"out_date":45677}
{"date":Date(12455),"out_date":45677} #invalid json because of Date(...)
{"date":12455,"out_date":45677,"other_date":12345} #valid json because of Date(...)
{"date":12455,"foo":"bar"}
{"date":12455,"out_date":Date(45677),"other_date":Date(12345)} #invalid json because of Date(...)
```

So basically, there are some strings in which I have this "Date(...)" field in it.
Not all strings have it.
Some strings have it multiple times.

Besides "replace(...)" is there a better way to replace all the "Date(...)" from it..
For example

```
{"date":12455,"out_date":Date(45677),"other_date":Date(12345)} becomes:
{"date":12455,"out_date":45677,"other_date":12345}
```

Basically, I want to convert these jsons into valid json..

Comment: What is generating the output with `Date`?  Seems like you should fix that problem.  Also, are you sure you don't want to use `Date` somehow instead of just removing that part?

Comment: @ExplosionPills  Well.. this is data I have got from public api.. So.. I have filed the report.. No.. I just want to parse these json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: import re

In [7]: re.sub("Date\((.+?)\)",r"\1",'{"date":Date(12455),"out_date":45677}')
Out[7]: '{"date":12455,"out_date":45677}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub(r"Date\((.*?)\)", r"\1", input)
```